# Obtener valor de EditText en un Toast

Tags: android, android-toast

Estoy empezando en android y estoy haciendo un programa en el cual tengo varios `EditText` y al momento de darle click a un botón me mande un Toast con toda la información de cada uno de los Edit text, como puedo hacer que mande el toast pero con la información de cada uno de los `EditText` pero en un Toast

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button butoon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        butoon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Nombre);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La reservacion ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        );

        Toast(text);
        toast.show();
    }

    private Toast Toast(EditText text)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El segundo parámetro que recepta `Toast.makeText()` es un `CharSequence`. Puedes obtener el texto de un `EditText` utilizando `EditText.getText()`, y luego convertirlo a `String` a través del método `toString()`. En tu código esto sería:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Nombre);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La reservación " + text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    toast.show();
}
```

¡Me avisas si funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente para usar este metodo de esta forma recibiendo como parametro una vista

```
public void onClick(View v){
```

debes llamarlo desde la propiedad `android:onClick` desde tu Layout o tu clase implementa la clase `onClicklistener`, al parecer es así ya que estas definiendo el listener de esta forma:

```
butoon.setOnClickListener(this);
```

---

Para agregar el valor del `EditText` simplemente obtenlo de esta  forma, obteniendo el `CharSequene` y convertirlo a `String` mediante el metodo `toString()`

```
String valorEditText = text.getText().toString();
```

Tu codigo seria de esta forma

```
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Nombre);
        String valorEditText = text.getText().toString();  
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La reservacion " + valorEditText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       /*No es necesaria esta forma 
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La reservacion ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        );

        Toast(text);
        toast.show();*/
    }
    /*metodo no necesario
    private Toast Toast(EditText text)
    {
        return null;
    }*/
```

Si tienes varios `EditText` obtén el texto que tiene dentro mediante

```
 String valorEditText1 = text1.getText().toString();
 String valorEditText2 = text2.getText().toString();
 String valorEditText3 = text3.getText().toString();
 ...
 ...
```

y concatenalos al mensaje del toast.

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar el text fuera del codigo de click y onCreate, para que lo puedas reutilizar en cualquier parte que desees, lo que quieres hacer se hace con `getText().toString()`, te deje un comentario ahí y te dejo un link abajo si quieres personalizarlo aun más.

```
EditText text;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Nombre);
        Button butoon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        butoon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
     String dato = text.getText().toString();
     /* El metodo getText() obtiene el dato escrito con el metodo toString()
     se convierte a String para poder manipularlo como tal, por ultimo
     se muestra en el textView con el metodo .setText()
     */
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dato,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();
    }
```

[Interesante información aquí para perzonalizar un más el Toast](https://danielme.com/tip-android-24-notificaciones-toast-personalizadas/)